# How to detect when an Azure Website has reached its quota in Shared mode ? When it's time to scale?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Imagine you publish a new Azure Website. You start with the "Shared" mode because you don't really know if it will be a success and if you will have lot of traffic or not.

How do you monitor your site to known if there are some quota overhead ? How do you know if it's time to switch to a reserved instance ?
Please avoid some non reliable solutions such as periodic check from an external service, which is just sampling.

I'd like to know, for example, how many times my site was down due to quota overhead.
What is the official Microsoft recommendation for that ? Is there an API I can use to receive and log these kind of events ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do that.You can have a graphical interface, a command-line interface, or just an API so you can incorporate the management into your own tools, or have third-party companies write other tools.

Some of them are :

The Windows Azure Management Portal

Windows Azure Management API

PowerShell Command-lets

SQL Server Management Studio / Data Tools / Visual Studio

Open-Source Tools

For get full details about [**Management and Monitoring Tools for Windows Azure**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckwoody/archive/2012/07/03/management-and-monitoring-tools-for-windows-azure.aspx)

**UPDATE**

By using below mentioned links you can View usage quotas for a web site

[**How to Monitor Web Sites**](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/how-to-monitor-websites/)

[**Great Improvements to Windows Azure Web Sites**](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/09/17/announcing-great-improvements-to-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx)

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: Thanks for you answer and link. I read your link carefully but found nothing about Windows Azure Web Sites (WAWS). All is about Azure Cloud Services (web and worker roles for example).

Comment: WAWS has specific limitations in Shared mode, such as a max CPU usage of 2.5 minutes in a 5 minutes period. The Azure Portal gives me absolute values (such as 400 sec of CPU usage between 4pm and 5pm), but I don't care about these values. I even don't know if theses values are high or not, and I don't want to know. I just need to know if a quota has been reached one time or not... just to know if my site has been down one time, or more, because of the quota.

Comment: @JYL Please check my "UPDATE" section.